# How to set rules for server?

Tags: c#, windows, email, exchangewebservices

I am working on Email Application. I want to set Rules for my application.

Ex. If a mail arrives from xyz@gmail.com, it should automatically move to junk folder.

Same as above I want to set few rules for junk and block sender. I am using Mail.dll to perform all the email task. As it has limitation, I can't create rules to server. Currently I must manage rules manually for every email which is overhead to the performance of the system as there are hundreds of emails drop in the email folder everyday.

Can anybody please suggest me how to create rules? I use Mail.dll for known servers and use EWS for exchange server.

Please suggest

Comment: I don't see why writing your own logic to define rules would be any less performant than if the library supported it for you. Hundreds of emails should take a negligible amount of time to sort.

Comment: @Rob Yes. You are right. I am using Mail.dll. It doesn't provide such functionality. See this: http://www.limilabs.com/qa/2084/how-to-block-specific-email-and-server

Answer (score 0):

For EWS you can use the Rule Operations https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff597938(v=exchg.80).aspx the only constraint is the Exchange Server version must be 2010 SP1 or above.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: I have checked. I have 9 different types of conditions. I got almost. But I am not getting about this 2 conditions. 1- Mail received with attachement should move to Specific folder. 2- Mail which is marked as Important should move to Specific folder. I have tried by this but doesn't work. `newRule.Conditions.HasAttachments;`